# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am new in Docker and CI\CD
I am using a vps with Ubuntu 18.04.
The docker of the project runs locally and works fine.
I don't quite understand why the server is trying to find the docker on http, not on tcp.

- override.conf

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

docker service status

[image]

- daemon.json

```
{ "storage-driver":"overlay" }
```

- gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker/compose:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - deploy
variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    # - export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
    - docker-compose stop || true
    - docker-compose up -d 
    - docker ps 

  environment:
    name: production
```

- Error

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks. Using images  is usually barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, visually impaired people cannot use their voice synthesizer, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed, it uses 1000x more data volume than the equivalent text. And above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: Ok, i will, thanks @Zeitounator.

Comment: Your job should output logs from the service container if it fails to start. Can you share any relevant parts of the job log above the error? (lines 1 -> 105). Your job is trying to connect on `127.0.0.1:2375` which is not correct for this kind of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable. When using the `docker:dind` service, the default hostname for the daemon is the name of the service, `docker`.

```yaml
variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
```

You must have also setup your GitLab runner to enable privileged containers.

Answer (score 0):

`docker` needs root permission to be access. If you want to run docker commands, or `docker-compose` from a regular user, you need to add your user to `docker` group like:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker yourUserName
```

By doing that, you can up your services and other docker stuffs with your regular user. If you don't want to add your user into docker group, you need to always prefix sudo on every docker commando you run:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already done this and the result is the same. the problem is that when server build pipline, look at http not tcp, the docker is deployed on localhost port 2375 on TCP.